# Extract IP address from HTML document

Tags: html, web-scraping, wget

How can I print the IP address (86.23.215.130) of the following line? The entire file (not shown) is the stdout from a wget (hence HTML). Sounds easy, but I didn't manage.

```
...
<tr><td align=center colspan=3 bgcolor="D0D0D0"><font face="Arial, Monospace" size=+3>86.23.215.130</font></td></tr>
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Note: <font> and some of your attributes are obsolete as of HTML5. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features

Answer (score 4):

Why sed? I believe grep is much better:

```
grep -iohP '(?<=\x3e)([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+(?=\x3c)' file
```

where \x3e means > and \x3c means < (ascii hex code)

Although sed can do this, but it's not recommended:

```
sed -rn 's/.*\x3e(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+)\x3c.*/\1/p' file
```

Thanks to Mr. Sternad, I improved this a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract the IP address only, you should use the following command:

```
sed -E -n 's/.*>([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)<.*/\1/p' file.txt
```

Here is what it does:

- `-E` switches sed into extended regex mode (-r in GNU Sed)
- `-n` suppresses the output of matched lines
- `'s/something/something2/p'` substitutes something with something2 and prints the resulting match
- `([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)` captures a group of four consecutive digits, separated by dots
- \1 is a reference to the captured group above

Note that this regex does not necessarily find correct IP addresses, but any sequence of digits, separated by dots.

If you want more flexibility (and accuracy), you could use the [Perl Commons Regex module](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2016020301/lib/Regexp/Common/net.pm). It validates IP addresses.

```
perl -MRegexp::Common -lne 'print $1 if /($RE{net}{IPv4})/' file.txt
```

Note that you have to correctly anchor your expression, otherwise an invalid IP, like `486.23.215.130` will be reduced to a valid address of `86.23.215.130`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the explanations! I have a separate code which validates IPv4 addresses. I'll post the outcome when finished.

Answer (score 2):

Ip addresses are four groups of 0-3 digits separated by 3 period points.

```
sed -e '/[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]/p' infile.txt
```

Comment: I believe `[0-9]` should be `[0-9]+`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, mine would only find single digits.

Comment: Nope. Even with `+`, it returns the entire infile.txt.

Comment: Then you would have to use perl , the same regexp enclosed in () ,and the **$&** backreference would contain the IP address, and only that.

Answer (score 0):

What about this here?
Any remarks?

```
grep "size=+3" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $7}'
```

I know ... it assumes that the IP is always at the same place in the line containing `size+3`. Your suggestions are all far more generally formulated, hence better applicable to any parse input text.