# Fully Iterate/Scrape a HTML document in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am fairly new to Web-Development, including HTML/CSS and also Javascript.

Is there a way to scrape a whole HTML Document, looking for certain patterns in it's inner text, using only vanilla JS?

I need to extract/identify different forms of IP Adresses from the Document, even those that are not marked in an "a"-tag but are still compliant with the rfc's textual representation of an IP Adress.

This functionality is supposed to be part of an Addon that is written using Mozilla's WebExtensions API. Thus I'm trying to abstain from using external libraries.

thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

how about the following,

```
grep -iohP '(?<=\x3e)([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+(?=\x3c)' file
```

refer:[Extract IP address from HTML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101699/extract-ip-address-from-html-document)

Though in js you may have to use **jQuery.grep()**

Answer (score 0):

Regex is probably your best bet in this case if the patterns can show up anywhere. for instance, to match every instance of a telephone number that's separated by hyphens, `myhtmlstring.match(/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g)` will return an array of all substrings that match that pattern.